# Primefaces Collapse LayoutUnit with another button

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I've been trying to add some functionality to expand/collapse a layoutUnit in primefaces, however I can't seem to get it to work. I've found two other answers on here but neither of them work for me:

[Primefaces, how to collapse layoutUnit using some script or jquery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853308/primefaces-how-to-collapse-layoutunit-using-some-script-or-jquery-function)

[Primefaces,how to collapse layoutUnit with another button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831933/primefaces-how-to-collapse-layoutunit-with-another-button)

For example I've tested the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:pf="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <pf:layout fullPage="true" widgetVar="layoutWdgt">
            <pf:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header="Top" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <h:form>
                    <pf:commandButton value="Toggle" onclick="layoutWdgt.toggle('west')"/>
                </h:form>
            </pf:layoutUnit>

            <pf:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header="Left" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <h:form>
                    <h:outputText value="West Layout unit"/>
                </h:form>
            </pf:layoutUnit>
            <pf:layoutUnit position="center">
                <h:outputText value="Center Layout unit"/>
            </pf:layoutUnit>
        </pf:layout>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And this doesn't work. The default expand collapse icon on the title of the west layoutunit expands/collapses the west layoutUnit, however the 'Toggle' button in the north layoutUnit just seems to reload the page without changing anything.

This is using primefaces 5. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it was because you need to use the 'PF' function to get the layout widget, ie:

```
 <pf:commandButton value="Toggle" onclick="PF('layoutWdgt').toggle('west')"/>
```

Although this isn't mentioned in the other posts I specified, I can only assume this became necessary in later PrimeFaces versions.